# Search rails app for integer on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, heroku, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

I am adding a search bar to my rails app. It works perfectly to find text, but I also want to search my "date" field, which is an integer. I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, but I have looked everywhere online and can't figure it out. I'm running MySQL locally, and it works fine, because the database is converting "date" to a string. When I push to Heroku it breaks, because the PG database wants to search for a integer. 
Here is my code, which works perfectly on MySQL:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    losearch = search.downcase
    find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(description) LIKE ? OR lower(artist) LIKE ? OR     lower(album) LIKE ? OR lower(date) LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%"], order: "created_at desc")
  else
    find(:all, order: "created_at desc")
  end
end
```

I know that the date should be something like date = ?, but I'm not quite figuring it out.

Comment: You have to first decide what date format you are going to allow the user to type in

Comment: My field is only titled "date". The user enters a year. For example, they will just enter "2011". I want to search 2011 in the search bar and have it return the items with 2011 entered. It works with MySQL because 2011 is converted to the string 2011. Heroku doesn't like that though...

Comment: did you try `search.to_s.downcase` ? Since `2011` is coming in as an integer, first convert to string and then do the rest of the processing

Comment: So your `date` column is actually an integer which holds the year number and if someone searches for 11 you'd want to find years `1109`, `1911`, `2011`, and `2112`?

Comment: Rajesh - I still get the error on Heroku with search.to_s.downcase. It could be a Heroku issue, because sometimes it takes time to update. I'll let you know.

Comment: mu - No, it's a review site for music. The user enters the year an album was released as part of the form. I want to search the database for 2011 and have it find those reviews with integers of 2011.

Comment: So if you're testing for equality, why are you trying to use LIKE at all?

Comment: LIKE works for the text field and it all works in MySql locally. Here is the site if it helps: http://thetens.us

Comment: I could just change the format of date to a string, which will work locally, but will that blow up my app database on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

The only correct answer anyone can give you is that you must use PostgreSQL in development, since you are using PostgreSQL in production. You will continue to experience problems as long as your development database is so different from your production database. If you develop on a Mac, try installing [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com), it's one click. Add the `pg` gem to your Gemfile and you should be all set.